# Binding two commands on one event

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to bind an action to two commands that will be done one after the other. I've tried the following syntax:

```
$g marker bind $point <Button-1> [list $table HighLightCell 1 [expr [lindex $value 1] + 3] \; __highlight_selected $table $sparam $eyes sparam_eyes $graph]
```

I've also tried few other variations, but none of them worked.

`$g` is a blt graph, and it handles binds like normal binds in Tk. What happens is that Tcl thinks that all the parameters are parameters for `$table HighLightCell` and doesn't interprate the `;` as the end of one command and start of a new command.

I can't use `{...}` syntax because I need to put variables in the commands, which I'm not able  to do using `{...}`. How can I put 2 commands that will be done when the event happens, without creating a new proc that will call those commands?

Comment: creating the new proc is much cleaner - why don't you want to do that?

Comment: Its probably even faster, as proc's get bytecompiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if I agree that the `proc` way is the better one, you can try the following two ways.

The first one, is to use double quotes for grouping, `"..."`, which are similar to braces, but allows variable expansion and command substitution. Your code will be something like:

```
$g marker bind $point <Button-1> "$table HighLightCell 1 [expr [lindex $value 1] + 3] ; __highlight_selected $table $sparam $eyes sparam_eyes $graph"
```

(Note that the semicolon is not escaped.)

The second one, is to use `eval`, and to defer the execution of the two commands to it. You can try this:

```
$g marker bind $point <Button-1> [list eval $table HighLightCell 1 [expr [lindex $value 1] + 3] \; __highlight_selected $table $sparam $eyes sparam_eyes $graph]
```

`eval` just calls the interpreter on a command formed by its arguments. If among them there is a semicolon, the commands will be two. The semicolon must be escaped, this time, because it must be interpreted by the `eval` and not before.

I tried both the methods with the following simple codes, and they both works:

```
set x 1
set y 2
pack [button .b1 -text Test1]
pack [button .b2 -text Test2]
bind .b1 <Button-1> "puts $x; puts $y"
bind .b2 <Button-2> [list eval puts $x \; puts $y]
```

Clicking on either the buttons gives the same result, which is the expected

```
1
2
```

One more thing, it's better to put the arguments of the `expr` command inside braces, so in your code you should replace

```
expr [lindex $value 1] + 3
```

with

```
expr {[lindex $value 1] + 3}
```

You don't have to worry about the substitution of the `$value` variable and about the execution of the `lindex` command: `expr` does that for you, but it also optimize the execution. You can find some more information in the wiki (http://wiki.tcl.tk/583), or in the `expr` manual page (http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/expr.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Use `+` at the beginning of the next script to bind, like this:

```
bind . <KeyPress-a> "puts one"
bind . <KeyPress-a> "+ puts two"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `list` command only ever constructs invokations of single commands. That's what it does (well, and building lists too but that doesn't matter so much here). You want to use two commands, so you should put the semicolon (or a newline) *outside* two `list` calls that generate the commands that are separated, like this:

```
$g marker bind $point <Button-1> [list \
        $table HighLightCell 1 [expr [lindex $value 1] + 3]
    ]\;[list \
        __highlight_selected $table $sparam $eyes sparam_eyes $graph]
```

However, I really advise using a small helper procedure at this point. It will save you much confusion in the long run.

```
proc DoSomeHighlighting {table value sparam eyes sparam_eyes graph} {
    $table HighLightCell 1 [expr {[lindex $value 1] + 3}]
    __highlight_selected $table $sparam $eyes sparam_eyes $graph
}

# Can be a number of lines of code in here, of course

$marker bind $point <1> [list DoSomeHighlighting $table $value $sparam $eyes $sparam_eyes $graph]
```

This becomes especially important once you decide that you've got to do more computing of values at runtime.